# How To pass hash into URL from page to iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page that is something like this:

```
http://mypage.com/about#peter
```

in the html of that page I have an iframe:

```
<iframe src="doit" />
```

I want the #peter to go to the iframe.  that is,I want the iframe rendered to be

```
<iframe src="doit#peter />
```

Any tips on how top make that happen?

thanks

Comment: I have tried the top line in the hopes that html would have been smart enough to pass the hash tag to the iframe.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the iframe programmatically when the page runs and attach the hash tag to it.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://mypage.com/about" + hash); 
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```